# Search RDL Files with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have an issue where we have hundreds of RDL files that we need to search through for specific tables, queries, key words, etc. I was told by someone you can load them into visual studio and use visual studio to search the XML. I cannot figure out how to search for keywords in the XML in visual studio. I used this procedure to download the RDL files to my machine. I have also created and added a project in Visual Studio, I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to search through the xml without clicking on each individual report and viewing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Edit => Find and replace => Find in files (Ctrl + Shift + F) and enter your search query. You can use Regular expressions in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install notepad++

In the file explorer search for all .rdl files.

Select all files, right click and select edit with notepad++

In the application use the search feature to find the particular strings in all open documents

[image]